# How to prove this is a probability density function?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, problem-solving, density-function

Being θ an aleatory variable with a uniform distribution function on the interval (-pi/2 , pi/2). Knowing that x = cos θ. How can I prove that this is a probability density function?

Can anyone here explain me how I get to know the analytic expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First calculate the CDF of your uniform rv.

Then, observe that

$$P(X> x)=F_{\Theta}(arccos (x))-F_{\Theta}(-arccos(x))=\frac{2}{\pi}arccos(x)$$

Thus, just using the definition of CDF you get

$$F_X(x)=1-\frac{2}{\pi}arccos(x)$$

Deriving you get the requested density

$$f_X(x)=\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}\mathbb{1}_{(0;1)}(x)$$

EDIT: if  you do not like the use of the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), the density can be expressed in the following form

$$ f_X(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}},  & \text{if $x \in (0;1)$ } \\
0, & \text{elsewhere}
\end{cases}$$

---

To prove that $f_X(x)$ is a nice density you can verify that all the density's properties are attained

1. $f_X(x)\geq 0$, $\forall x$
2. $\int_{\infty}^{\infty}f_X(x)dx=1$

EDIT2: Here are the passages for the integral

$$\int_0^1\frac{2}{\pi\sqrt{1-x^2}}dx=\frac{2}{\pi}\Big[-arccos(x)\Big]_0^1=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}=1$$

The same properties can be verified directly on the CDF

1. $F(-\infty)=0$
2. $F(\infty)=1$
3. $\frac{d}{dx}F_X(x)\geq 0$, $\forall x$

Comment: in the requested density what is that 1 and that (0;1)?

Comment: @Ognum : the random variable $\Theta$ is defined in $(-\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2})$. If you do a drawing you realize that $X$'s support is $(0;1)$.

Comment: I verified and the integral of that funtion is not equal to 1...

Comment: @Ognum: verify again because I assure you that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=1$. The integral is not necessary because this can be verified by $F_X(1)=1$. Anyway I edited my answer with the passages for the integral

Comment: yeah now I got it. thank you so much